# Optimising table structure for Monday period 1-9

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way to optimise the below table?

```
// Monday period 1

echo '
<td class="gridSide">Mon</td>
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon1">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 1
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 2

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon2">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 2
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 3

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon3">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 3
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 4

echo 
'<td class="box" id="grid2_mon4">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 4
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 5

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon5">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 5
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 6

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon6">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 6
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 7

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon7">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 7
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 8

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon8">'; 
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 2
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';

// Monday period 9

echo '
<td class="box" id="grid2_mon9">';
$sql = "
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 2
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_id' => $room) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $rows.'<br>free';
echo '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main need is to index columns used to select the rows - in the ON and WHERE clauses.  Use composite indexes when you are using multiple columns, typically putting the lowest cardinality column first.

Additional performance gains can usually be had by putting the columns from the SELECT clause in the index, allowing MySQL to read everything that it needs from the index without reading the underlying record from disk.

Oh, and any time you're repeating the same query, think about refactoring something.